# How can I display form validation messages on the same page as the form itself?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple html form with a single field that submits to download.php which validates the form and finally sends me back an email with the user input.  So far, everything works great - but I would like the error messages and thank you message to display inside the original html form, not on a new page (as is happening now).

Can you tell me how to keep myform.html visible after the submit button is clicked, and load the error and thank you messages inside the "notification" div?

BTW, just in case it's relevant, myform.html is dynamically displayed inside a  on index.html using jQuery .load().

Thanks for your help!

myform.html

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>

    <div id="notification"></div> <!-- want to load errors and thank you, here -->

    <form id="downloadForm" method="post" action="_php/download.php">

        <label for="biz_email">Business Email:</label><input type="text" name="biz_email">

        <div id="submit" class="submit_button"></div>
        <!-- FYI submit function called in separate jQuery file -->

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

download.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['biz_email'])) {


    $email_to = "foo@bar.com"; //my email
    $email_subject = "form submission";
    $email_from ="form test";

    $biz_email = $_POST['biz_email'];
    $error_message = "";


    // validation
    ...


    //error code 
    function died($error) {
        echo "There are errors in your submission:<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    //email message (sent back to me)
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($biz_email)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$biz_email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$biz_email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

    <!-- thank you message -->

    Success!

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Two ways to accomplish that - 1) Post the page to itself and do the error checking at the beginning of the script; 2) Use AJAX (i.e., jQuery's validation plugin) to test all the data before you POST it to the new page.  http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: thanks DevlshOne, I'll tinker and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following to post the form with AJAX:

```
$('#downloadForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't let the form get submitted the normal way

    $.post("download.php", $('#downloadForm').serializeArray()).then(function (data) {
        $('notification').html(data);
    }, function (error) {
        $('notification').html("Network error submitting form - please try again");
    });
});
```

There's a lot of improvements that can be made to this, but hopefully it's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the $.post function.

So it would look like this:

```
    <label for="biz_email">Business Email:</label><input type="text" name="biz_email" id="biz_email">

    <div id="submit" class="submit_button" onclick="submitForm();"></div>
    <!-- FYI submit function called in separate jQuery file -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(){

var biz_email = $("#biz_email").val();

$.post('THE URL OF THE PHP FILE YOUR POSTING TO', {biz_email: biz_email}, function(result){

$("#notification").html(result);

});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an empty `action` and post the form to itself. That way, you'll be able to display the errors in the same page:

**The structure:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//validation
}

<form action="" method="post">
<!-- input fields here -->
</form
```

**Full code:**

```
<?php

if(isset( $_POST['submitbutton']) ){
$email_to = "foo@bar.com"; //my email
$email_subject = "form submission";
$email_from ="form test";
$biz_email = $_POST['biz_email'];
$error_message = "";

function died($error) {
echo "There are errors in your submission:<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($biz_email)."\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$biz_email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$biz_email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);          
}    
?>

<!-- form start -->
<div id="notification"></div>
<form id="downloadForm" method="post" action="">
<label for="biz_email">Business Email:</label><input type="text" name="biz_email">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitbutton" class="submit_button"></div>
</form>
<!-- form end -->
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me I would use the server side function of php that is the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

Just change the form action in your code something like

```
 <form id="downloadForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Then paste your download.php code inside your `myform.html` and change the extention to `.php`

But enclose the code to `if` for validation like:

```
if(isset($_POST['biz_email'])) { 
    //your download.php code here
}
```

Then just make a validation inside your `div` `notification`

```
<div id="notification">
   <?php echo $error_message; ?>
</div> <!-- want to load errors and thank you, here -->

//this is all php code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some ajax validation **onblur** or **onchange** event of textbox.

otherwise you can call **onsubmit** event of submit button. You can use below function for above things.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('body').on('blur','#filedname',function()  {jQuery("#validation").html('Validating data.....');jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','url':'download.php','cache':false,'data':{data: $('#formid').serializeArray()},'success':function(html)       {jQuery("#validation").html(html)}});return false;});
}); 

<div id='validation'>Validation result</div>
```